# Coding a multiplayer chess game: HTML5 Canvas + ReactJS vs. Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, html5-canvas, chess

I'm going to start coding a project with friends. It consists in developing a multiplayer chess for fun. In terms of tech, it includes WebSockets for multiplayer interactivity and Javascript for backend and frontend.

I read a lot of articles and sources and I couldn't find a satisfactory answer on this matter: what frontend stack would be optimal to code the chessboard UI, visual animations (we'd like to make fun 2D animations when pieces are eaten and such), song queues.

I read that one can either do it exclusively in JS / HTML, maybe make use of the  tag, or use Phaser 3 for 2D animation on HTML. But I couldn't find the associated pros and cons. I know every stack comes with its upsides and downsides and that there isn't one single option.

My goal would be to find a stack that makes adding sound and visual animations easy on top of the 2D chessboard and game logic while being compatible with socket.io, Express, and most NodeJS middleware.

Thank you so much for your help and time. Have a good one!

Eiki

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is combination of Phaser 3 and ReactJS.
Phaser 3 will cover most of the game while ReactJS will be used in combination with Phaser 3 DOM object to develop the UI of the game.

I already have an example of multiplayer game written in Phaser 3 + ReactJS as a client side and NodeJS (Rivalis multiplayer framework) on the backend side.

https://github.com/rivalis/rivalis-demo

I hope this will be useful for you.